# Calculate angles that are in degrees (clockwise) to radians (counter clockwise)

Tags: python, pygame

First, I am aware of how converting degrees in radians.

I need to draw an arc given a coordinate, radius, and two angles in degrees clockwise in [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news). For example:

```
point = (50, 50)
startAngle = 320
endAngle = 140
```

should draw something like

[image]

and

```
point = (50, 50)
startAngle = 90
endAngle = 180
```

should draw something like

[image]

etc.

I have tried reverting the angle (i.e. `360 - angle`) but pygame draws the arc in reverse; instead of a 45⁹ arc in the last image, I get a 270⁹ arc that is the complement of what I want.

I guess I'm having a brain fart day because I can't figure this out. Thank you!

---

**Edit** : I may have an answer, though I'm not sure if it is a good one. If I reverse the angles and negate them, it seems to draw them correctly clockwise. For example, given the first example :

```
point = (50, 50)
startAngle = 360 - 140
endAngle = 360 - 320
```

seems to correctly draws the arc where expected.

Comment: have you tried simply `-angle`, rather than `360-angle`?

Comment: Also, for reversed direction of the arc, you seem to need to swap between the start and end angles

Comment: No angles are reversed in the details of this question, and negating the angles don't work, no. **However**, reverting the angles and negating them seems to work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to draw an clockwise arc, then you've to **invert** the angles and you've to **swap** the start and end angle:

```py
def clockwiseArc(surface, color, point, radius, startAngle, endAngle):
    rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, radius*2, radius*2)
    rect.center = point

    endRad   = math.radians(-startAngle)
    startRad = math.radians(-endAngle)

    pygame.draw.arc(surface, color, rect, startRad, endRad)
```

e.g.:

```py
clockwiseArc(window, (255, 0, 0), (150, 70), 50, 300, 140) 
clockwiseArc(window, (255, 0, 0), (300, 70), 50, 90, 180)
```

[image]